# Card view doesn't work when added inside scroll view

Tags: xml, scrollview, android-cardview, android-scrollview, cardview

The cards are aligned properly with Linear Layout but everything squishes into the top of the screen once I change it to Scroll View.

When I change the 1st linear layout to scroll view, the cards all disappear. Even nested scroll view does not work.

This is the tutorial I followed to make this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=go9q4O44b4E&list=PLjM-SORshDUo88dLfcepQWofORqwwOaP2&index=12&t=131s , but mine doesn't work when I add scroll view.

Please please help me, I have looked EVERYWHERE but I can't fix it!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


         <include
            android:id="@+id/action_bar2"
            layout="@layout/action_bar2">
         </include>


        <GridLayout android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="3"

            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="14dp">


            <!--Row 1-->
            <!--Column 1-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="9dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="9dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >


                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/art" />


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="#Art"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--Column 2-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="9dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="9dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="203dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/education" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="#Education"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--Row 2-->
        <!--Column 1-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="9dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="9dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/entertain" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="#Entertainment"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="19sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textAlignment="center"/>

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--Column 2-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="9dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="9dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">


                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/fashion"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:text="#Fashion"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--Row 3-->
            <!--Column 1-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="9dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="9dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/date" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="#Dating"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--Column 2-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:cardElevation="9dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/music" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="#Music"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
         </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it may work...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.shreya.chatapplication.TopicsActiviy">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/action_bar2"
        layout="@layout/action_bar2"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:rowCount="3">


            <!--Row 1-->
            <!--Column 1-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
                app:cardElevation="9dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">


                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/art" />


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="#Art"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--Column 2-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
                app:cardElevation="9dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="203dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/education" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="#Education"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--Row 2-->
            <!--Column 1-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
                app:cardElevation="9dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/entertain" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="#Entertainment"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="19sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--Column 2-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
                app:cardElevation="9dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">


                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/fashion" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="#Fashion"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--Row 3-->
            <!--Column 1-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
                app:cardElevation="9dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/date" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="#Dating"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!--Column 2-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"
                app:cardElevation="9dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/music" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="#Music"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped with keeping the cards in proper place without all shrinking to the top, but it does not help with scroll. The page still does not scroll. When I add new cards, they adjust themselves onto the same page by adjusting their sizes. Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Thank you so much the page scrolls now! But now the only problem is the cards adjusting themselves onto a single page which is why the scroll doesn't need to appear.